# Detect if using nextJS, react or react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, next.js

I'm building a library working with React apps.
Since it will be working on the React ecosystem, some features are going to work differently according to the environment.

I'm looking for a way to detect whether the current environment is a ReactJS app (made with create-react-app for example), or if it's using NextJS over it for the SSR, or if it's a mobile app made with React Native.

Does it exist a javascript way to know this information?

Thank you :)

Comment: What features are you looking to modify based on dev environment?

Comment: It's quite difficult to explain you completely what I'm going to change, but basically it works differently depending on the env because the lib is using async-storage (on RN) and js-cookie on ReactJS, but also have to handle if the code is executed on the server side of nextJS.

Comment: Can you use a state manager for your storage needs?  Redux for example has good solutions for working across all three platforms.

Comment: expose a prop that your consumer will specify the mode

Comment: @Abe No, it needs to be hard stored

Comment: @felixmosh Yeah thought about this but wanted something with automatic detection. Anyway, If I can't figure out I'll use this way.

Comment: @Fantasim for what it's worth, redux-persist now requires RN users to explicitly pass in a storage container.  It looks like all the ones [here](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#storage-engines) have `getItem`, `setItem`, and `removeItem` methods.  This might be the lowest-friction solution for dev & user.

Comment: Alright thank you ! gonna use this system

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if your code is running in react native, you can use navigator.product. React Native returns navigator.product as "ReactNative". Here is a link to the proposal which is implemented. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1331

To check whether your code is running in NextJS or Browser, you could check if `window` object or `document` object is defined or not. Under nodeJS, `window` is undefined.

React native has defined common browser objects like window and document to ensure libraries that target browsers work. Here is a link to the code.  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Core/InitializeCore.js